# Diagonalization of a tridiagonal, symmetric sparse matrix with Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I have an NxN symmetric and tridiagonal matrix computed by a Python code and I want to diagonalize it.

In the specific case I'm dealing with `N = 6000`, but the matrix can become larger. Since it is sparse, I assumed the best way to diagonalize it was to use the algorithm `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh()`, which performed extremely good with other sparse and symmetric matrices (not tridiagonal ones, though) I worked with. In particular, since I need only the low lying part of the spectrum, I'm specifying `k=2` and `which='SM'` in the function.

However, in this case this algorithm seems not to work, since after approximately 20 minutes of computation I get the following error:

> ArpackNoConvergence: ARPACK error -1: No convergence (60001 iterations, 0/2 eigenvectors converged)

Why is this happening? Is it a problem related to some properties of tridiagonal matrices? Which Python (and please, only Python!) routine can I use in order to diagonalize my matrix in an efficient way?

Here's the requested minimal code to reproduce my error:

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sl
import numpy as np

dim = 6000
a = np.empty( dim - 1 )
a.fill( 1. )
diag_up = np.diag( a, 1 )
diag_bot = np.diag( a, -1 )

b = np.empty( dim )
b.fill( 1. )

mat = np.diag( b ) + diag_up + diag_bot
v, w = sl.eigsh(mat, 2, which = 'SM')
```

On my pc the construction of the matrix takes 364ms, while the diagonalization gives the reported error.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? Could there be a problem with casting? `scipy.sparse` functions work with sparse arrays, which have a different representation in memory and maybe what you are observing is related to this? Have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1063520312001042) very useful. *O(nlogn)* rocks

Comment: @norok2 done, thanks for answering.

Comment: I'd stick with `scipy.linalg.eigh()` if that works for you. Not sure why the function does not converge in this case.

Comment: @norok sorry for the late answer. scipy.linalg.eigh() is fast enough for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARPACK is good at finding the large-magnitude eigenvalues but can struggle to find the small ones. Fortunately, you can work around this quite easily by using the shift-invert options built into `eigsh`.  See, for example, [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/arpack.html).

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sl
import scipy.sparse as spr
import numpy as np

dim = 6000
diag = np.empty( dim )
diag.fill( 1. )

# construct the matrix in sparse format and cast to CSC which is preferred by the shift-invert algorithm
M = spr.dia_matrix((np.array([diag, diag, diag]), [0,-1, 1]), shape=(dim,dim)).tocsc()

# Set sigma=0 to find eigenvalues closest to zero, i.e. those with smallest magnitude. 
# Note: under shift-invert the small magnitued eigenvalues in the original problem become the large magnitue eigenvalue
# so 'which' parameter needs to be 'LM'
v, w = sl.eigsh(M, 2, sigma=0, which='LM')
print(v)
```

For this particular example problem, you can verify that the above is finding the correct eigenvalues since the eigenvalues happen to have an [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues):

```
from math import sqrt, cos, pi
eigs = [abs(1-2*cos(i*pi/(1+dim))) for i in range(1, dim+1)]
print(sorted(eigs)[0:2])
```

Comment: Perhaps swap `v` and `w` to match the typical convention in the SciPy docs. (Plus `v` then goes with vector!)

Answer (score 1):

Using `eigsh` may not be a good idea with regard to performance if you want more than a few eigenvalues. Instead, consider using `eigh_tridiagonal`, which uses the appropriate LAPACK routine (instead of ARPACK). Note that with `eigh_tridiagonal`, I do not think you can compute the smallest magnitude eigenvalues. You can compute all eigenvalues, eigenvalues corresponding to particular indexes, or eigenvalues within a particular range (see the [documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal.html)). I think the last option may be useful for your present purposes though.

Some example code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
from timeit import default_timer as timer

dim = 6000
diag = np.ones(dim)
offdiag = np.ones(dim - 1)

eig_range = (-0.005, 0.005) # center it on zero for the comparison with eigsh to work properly!

lapack_time = timer()
evals_lapack, evecs_lapack = la.eigh_tridiagonal(diag, offdiag, select = 'v', select_range = eig_range)
lapack_time = timer() - lapack_time
```

You can then make a comparison with the sparse ARPACK approach:

```
import scipy.sparse as spa
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sla

n_eigvals = np.size(evals_lapack)
evals_true = 1.0 - 2.0 * np.cos(np.arange(1, dim + 1) * np.pi / (dim + 1))
sm_idxs = np.argpartition(np.abs(evals_true), (0, n_eigvals))[:n_eigvals]
evals_true_sm = np.sort(evals_true[sm_idxs])

arpack_time = timer()
sparse_csc_matrix = spa.dia_matrix((np.array([diag, diag, diag]), [0, -1, 1]), shape = (dim, dim)).tocsc()
evals_arpack, evecs_arpack = sla.eigsh(sparse_csc_matrix, n_eigvals, sigma = 0, which = 'LM')
arpack_time = timer() - arpack_time

lapack_accuracy = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square((evals_lapack - evals_true_sm) / evals_true_sm)))
arpack_accuracy = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square((evals_arpack - evals_true_sm) / evals_true_sm)))

print("for", n_eigvals, "eigenvalues...")
print("are results the same?", np.allclose(evals_lapack, evals_arpack))
print("lapack time: ", lapack_time)
print("arpack time: ", arpack_time)
print("lapack error:", lapack_accuracy)
print("arpack error:", arpack_accuracy)
```

Some results:

```
for 11 eigenvalues...
are results the same? True
lapack time:  0.027329199999996945
arpack time:  0.1122953999999936
lapack error: 1.0656446384601465e-13
arpack error: 3.0175238399729594e-13

for 1137 eigenvalues...
are results the same? True
lapack time:  10.724007
arpack time:  62.3984447
lapack error: 4.6350742410143475e-14
arpack error: 3.0063051257502015e-14
```